# What plugins do I need for Dynamic Web Project or Spring MVC development in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I am looking for what plugins I need for Dynamic Web Project or Spring MVC development. The Eclipse installed my package manager of Arch Linux doesn't have that (as expected), and I don't want to download Eclipse EE if possible. I am sure I can accomplish the same result using the Eclipse I have now.

- I believe Dynamic Web Project will suffice, how do I get it up
- Also tried to install the Spring Toolkit but I keep getting dependencies errors (I suppose I should start with getting Dynamic Web Project up first ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go download the Eclipse Java EE package.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Search for Spring Source Tool Suite and install it.

This is all you need.  Hope it helps.